# MySQL: How to use alias to construct a new field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use two aliases (**like_count** and **dislike_count**) to construct a new field (**score**) that will be used for order purposes. Below is the current piece of query I have which does not work. I get the following error with the below query: ***"Unknown column 'like_count' in 'field list"***. I have looked for similar question on SO, but have not been able to find out a solution. Anyone has an idea how to do it?

```
SELECT comment.id, comment.content, 

SUM(if(comment_reaction.type = 'like', 1, 0)) as like_count,
SUM(if(comment_reaction.type = 'dislike', 1, 0)) as dislike_count,

((like_count + 1.9208) / (like_count + dislike_count) - 
    1.96 * SQRT((like_count * dislike_count) / (like_count + dislike_count) + 0.9604) / 
        (like_count + dislike_count)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (like_count + dislike_count))
as score,

(SELECT comment_reaction.type FROM comment_reaction
WHERE comment_reaction.person_id = :person_id
AND comment.id = comment_reaction.comment_id) as my_reaction

FROM comment
LEFT JOIN comment_reaction ON comment.id = comment_reaction.comment_id

WHERE comment.topic_id = :topic_id  
GROUP BY comment.id
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: You cant use alias field name in operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your original query up in a derived table. Then add your new column:

```
select dt.*,
    ((like_count + 1.9208) / (like_count + dislike_count) - 
        1.96 * SQRT((like_count * dislike_count) / (like_count + dislike_count) + 0.9604) / 
            (like_count + dislike_count)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (like_count + dislike_count))
    as score

from
(
SELECT 
    comment.id, comment.content, 

    SUM(if(comment_reaction.type = 'like', 1, 0)) as like_count,
    SUM(if(comment_reaction.type = 'dislike', 1, 0)) as dislike_count,

    (SELECT comment_reaction.type FROM comment_reaction
    WHERE comment_reaction.person_id = :person_id
    AND comment.id = comment_reaction.comment_id) as my_reaction,

    FROM comment
    LEFT JOIN comment_reaction ON comment.id = comment_reaction.comment_id

    WHERE comment.topic_id = :topic_id

    GROUP BY comment.id
) dt
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get only 10 most popular comments? Will this query get all comments and then apply LIMIT? If that is the case, then performance does not seem to be ok.

Comment: I see no LIMIT requirement in the question. Do you mean you want the 10 highest scores or what?

Comment: Yes, the question does not have that, but I would like to know the answer. Yes, I mean 10 highest scores. As I know, I will need to apply LIMIT to the outer query, however in that case, inner query will get all comments and then outer query will narrow it down, am I right? If that is the case, how will the performance be?

Comment: Then I'd put LIMIT 10 at the end. I don't know how the query will be optimized. It depends on the table data, statistics, indexes etc. How many rows are returned? You can move out the sub-qeury as well, but I don't know if that matters. Try and see.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Your solution works. I will accept your answer if other, more optimized answer does not show up.